# Python writing into csv without line break \r\n

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Python 3 and scrapy to crawl some data. For some instances, I have 2 sentences which would like to write to excel as comma separated csv file.
**How can I make them not to split into new line concernig the '\r\n'? Instead, how can I treat the whole sentence as a string**

The sentences are as below

> 'USBについての質問です\r\n下記のサイトの通りCentOS7を１USBからインストールしよう...',
>    'USBからインストールしよう...',

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a code snippet of how you are parsing the strings, it's a bit difficult to suggest how exactly you can solve your problem. Anyway, you can always use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to remove the occurrences of `\r\n` from your string:

```
>>> string = 'abc\r\ndef'
>>> print string
abc
def
>>> string.replace('\r\n', ' ')
'abc def'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write to a CSV file, I'd suggest you use pandas  dataframe as it make life whole lot a easier.

```
import pandas as pd
string="'USBについての質問です\r\n下記のサイトの通りCentOS7を１USBからインストールしよう...'\r\n'USBからインストールしよう...'"
string = string.repalce('\r\n',',')
list1=list(string)
df = pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=None,header=False)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice and possible solution provided above. Yet, I have found the way to solve it.

```
string="'USBについての質問です\r\n下記のサイトの通りCentOS7を１USBからインストールしよう...'\r\n'USBからインストールしよう...'"
string.replace('\r','\\r').replace('\n','\\n'')
```

Then write this string into the csv will make the csv show \r\n together with the other text as a whole string.